# Exporting LaTeX commands to HTML/MathJax

Tags: org-mode, latex, html, mathjax

I am writing a document that is specifying a language with associated grammar and semantics. For this I have written the specification in Latex, using a method very similar to the one [presented here](http://cgswords.github.io/latex-semantics/).

That is: it heavily uses Latex's `\newcommand` macros. However, the contents of the commands themselves are **nothing fancy** and falls *within* the subset of Latex that MathJax supports.

I am slowly rewriting my documentation to Org mode, partially because of the HTML backend, allowing me to not only generate the original-ish PDF, but also a HTML page containing the same.

Now my question is: how can I export my (big list of) Latex `\newcommand` macros to `Org` such that they get compiled back to their originals on the Latex backend, but to their MathJax equivalent when exporting with the HTML backend?

**Bonus question**: Is it possible to *redefine* macros in MathJax? My original version contains several iterations of the same things, and overloads the macros by simply calling `\renewcommand`. Ideally, I would replicate this in MathJax, but it is not a dealbreaker: I can "simply" append some version id to each new iteration of the command, i.e. `\somecommandA`, `\somecommandB` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding the following solution.

I found a [base solution on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/7u2n0h/tip_for_defining_latex_macros_for_use_in_both/) that adds a "fake" language to babel as follows:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("latex-macros" . latex))

(defvar org-babel-default-header-args:latex-macros
  '((:results . "raw")
    (:exports . "results")))

(defun prefix-all-lines (pre body)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert body)
    (string-insert-rectangle (point-min) (point-max) pre)
    (buffer-string)))

(defun org-babel-execute:latex-macros (body _params)
  (concat
   (prefix-all-lines "#+LATEX_HEADER: " body)
   "\n#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <div style=\"display: none\"> \\(\n"
   (prefix-all-lines "#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: " body)
   "\n#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: \\)</div>\n"))
```

This lets you define a `latex-macros` block as follows:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC latex-macros
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}
#+END_SRC
```

For the Latex output, because it uses `#+LATEX_HEADER`, the commands are put in the preamble. For the HTML output, because of the `HTML_HEAD_EXTRA`, it is also put somewhere in the top of the document.

This got near what I wanted, but not quite, as I wanted to be able to redefine commands. What I ended up doing was modifying the code to add a 2nd "fake" language `latex-macros-inline` that uses `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex` and `BEGIN_EXPORT html` blocks like so:

```lisp
(defvar org-babel-default-header-args:latex-macros-inline
  '((:results . "raw")
    (:exports . "results")))

(defun org-babel-execute:latex-macros-inline (body _params)
  (concat
   "\n#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex\n"
   body
   "\n#+END_EXPORT"
   "\n#+BEGIN_EXPORT html\n"
   "<div style=\"display: none\"> \n\\(\n"
   body
   "\n\\)\n</div>\n"
   "#+END_EXPORT"))
```

Because of these blocks, both the Latex and HMTL is outputted at the actual place the block is defined.